# setTimeout не работает в event listener

Tags: javascript

Почему-то не работает setTimeout внутри addEventListener.

```
<button id="button" class="search-form__btn" type="submit">Найти</button>

document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function () {
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('alert с таймером 3 секунды')
}, 3000)})
```

Должен через 3 сек после нажатия на кнопку выдать console.log(). Кнопка нажимается - ничего не происходит.

Comment: Проверил, всё работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в `type="submit"` - при отправке формы происходит перезагрузка и обработчик setTimeout просто не успевает выполниться.

Answer (score 0):

Видимо, проблема в чём-то другом, потому что ваш фрагмент работает:

```js
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function () {
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('alert с таймером 3 секунды')
}, 3000)})
```

```html
<button id="button" class="search-form__btn" type="submit">Найти</button>
```